# Allow only two instances of a character using RegEx

Tags: regex, c#

I am new to using regular expressions and I am trying to figure out something that would seem to be pretty easy.  I would like to identify if a character exists only twice within a string.  The character does not need to be two in a row, but a count of two anywhere in the string.  For instance, "41:08:05" is ok, but "41:08" or "41:08:05:02" would not be correct.  In this example I am looking for the existence of only two colons (:) anywhere in the string.

Comment: Programming questions are out of scope here at Super User

Answer (score 0):

I'll walk through this in English, pointing out each part of the regex, then show it in action. I'll answer the specific question you asked, then I'll point out some alternatives that may better suit your solution.

You want the pattern to start with the *beginning of the string*, so that we won't match strings that have our desired pattern as a substring. The regular expression character indicating the *beginning of a string* is `^`.

Then, we may have some characters prior to the first `:` character. Going by the wording of the question you asked, it's acceptable for the `:` character to be the first character in the string, so we'll look for *zero or more* characters that aren't `:`. The regular expression group for "a character that isn't `:` is `[^:]`, and following it will be the regular expression character for *zero or more*, `*`.

Then, we want to match the first `:`. We can do that with the plain `:` character.

Then, again, we'll look for *zero or more* characters that aren't `:`. Again, according to the wording of your question, there's no problem with the colons being adjacent to each other. Therefore, we'll add another `[^:]*`.

Then, we'll match another plain `:`.

Finally, we'll have *zero or more* non-`:` characters, followed by the *end of the string*. Interpreted into regex, that's `[^:]*$`.

Put that all together, and we have what you asked for:

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ echo '41:08:05' | egrep '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*$'
41:08:05
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ echo '41:08:05:02' | egrep '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*$'
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ echo '41:08' | egrep '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*$'
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$
```

This does allow for cases like this:

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ echo '::' | egrep '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*$'
::
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ echo ':abcdefg###:' | egrep '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*$'
:abcdefg###:
```

If you want something formatted like the example strings you gave, you'll want to ensure the non-`:` characters exist, are numeric, and come two at a time. I'll leave the explanation of this one as an exercise for the reader.

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ echo '41:08:05' | egrep '^[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}$'
41:08:05
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ echo '41:08' | egrep '^[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}$'
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ echo '41:08:05:02' | egrep '^[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}$'
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ echo '::' | egrep '^[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}$'
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ echo 'aa:bb:cc' | egrep '^[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}$'
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$
```

Note, this is using `egrep` regular expressions rather then the regex engine `c#` uses, but the two are analogous enough that you should be able to find the corresponding syntax easily (the biggest difference being the `[[:digit:]]` character class, which in other regex engines can usually be expressed as `[0-9]`.)